# Discrete Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The question is to find the moment generating function of

p(k) = Pr(X = k) = −p^k/(k*ln(1-p)
where p<1 and k=1,2,3...

Putting this into the formula, I have

Σe^(t*k)*p^k/(x*log(1-p))

but I am not sure what to do next.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the PMF is - $$P\left(X=k\right) =\frac{-p^k}{k.\ln \left(1-p\right)}$$
The MGF is given by - $$∑_{k=1}^∞\frac{-p^ke^{tk}}{\left(k.\ln \left(1-p\right)\right)}$$

$$ = ∑_{k=1}^∞\frac{{-\left(pe^{t}\right)}^{k}}{\left(k.\ln \left(1-p\right)\right)}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\ln \left(1-p\right)}∑_{k=1}^∞\frac{{-\left(pe^{t}\right)}^{k}}{k}$$
$$ = \frac{\ln \left(1-pe^t\right)}{\ln \left(1-p\right)}$$